# Stored Procedure for update not working

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am new to writing stored procedures, and i have some issues executing this one.it is able to update the name and address but is not able to update the `employeecount`.And i am not able to track the error i have made.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_update_company_details`(
IN p_id int(11),
IN p_name varchar(45),
IN p_address varchar(45),
IN p_num_employee int(11)   
)
BEGIN
UPDATE company
SET name=p_name,
    address=p_address,
    employeecount=p_num_employee
WHERE id=p_id;
END
```

And this the table in the database

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `employeecount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`logo` blob,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

A std table,not anything fancy.

And this is how iam calling this stored procedure.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("call sp_update_company_details({0},'{1}','{2}',{3})",
                   id,request.Name,request.Address,request.NumberOfEmployees), conn);
```

`id` and `request` are passed as parameter to the function where this call is made.

Comment: How are you calling it? It should either all succeed or all fail.

Comment: Are you sure `request.NumberOfEmployees` has the value you think it has?

Comment: @outlyer yes that was the error,there was some error in JSON object that i was passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly an issue with your calling code not the stored procedure. If you try executing it from workbench, it should succeed without any issues.

To clean-up and fix your code, you really should make your call (all of your calls and queries) paramaterized like so:

```
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("connString"))
        {
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_update_company_details"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_id", id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_name", request.Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_address", request.Address);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_num_employee", request.NumberOfEmployees);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

I would also do a step through to ensure that the values you think are being passed by request are actually the values you think they are.